# Why do I get an error when calling setState for class properties like the display property?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm trying to change the state of component A when a button (component B) is clicked. I get the handler to run at the right time, but I keep getting these errors about not being able to change certain properties like *display* in other components, such as component B (see img 2). I understand some things in react can't be modified but what I don't understand is why my code would work when originally loading but fail and throw errors when I'm simply changing the state of component A.

To be more specific, the original state of component A that I'm trying to change is seen in the attached img

[State before handler call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vqSn.png)

Then I click a button and the handler seen below is called

```
delete_list_item = id => {
        console.log("deleting : ", id);
        console.log("before : ", this.state)
        this.setState({
            test: 2
        }, ()=>{
            console.log("after : ", this.state)
        })
    }
```

If you look at the img above, you can see the id is passed in properly and I attempt to call setState. I'm simply trying to change the value of state.test from 1 to 2 as a test case. This is where I get many errors similar to the following img. Again before I call setState, I don't get these errors, but as soon as I do, a bunch of these errors are thrown.

[One of the errors I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR5WC.png)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *styles object* properties needed to be assigned within the initial declaration of the object since the object is or becomes read only.

Instead of

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    styles = {
        width: "50px"
    }

    render() {
        if(this.props.margin){
            styles.margin = this.props.margin
        }

        return <div style={this.styles}></div>
    }
}
```

I moved the conditional assignments to the initial definition of the *styles object* like this

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    styles = {
        width: "50px",
        margin: this.props.margin ? this.props.margin : "none"
    }

    render() {

        return <div style={this.styles}></div>
    }
}
```